# Using more than one ST_function in one query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have got stuck with a dynamic analysis that I would like to include in a project I am working with. I want to save the query in the project file or make it to a view in my database. I have tried a couple of combination without success so far, but I am on a SQL learning curve =).

I would like to combine the queries below so that my `ST_buffer` is used in the same query as the layer where `building.geom` need to be completely inside. 
Is this possible?

```
SELECT
    event_point.id,
    event_point.geom,
    st_buffer(event_point.geom, 100) AS "Buffer",

FROM public.event_point

SELECT 
    building.id
    building.address
FROM 
    building, "Buffer"
WHERE
    ST_within(building.geom, "Buffer".geom)
```

Comment: The question isn't totally clear. However, in general, it is better to use ST_DWithin than ST_Buffer -- it amounts to the same thing. Saying ST_DWithin(geom1, geom2, 1000) is the same as saying ST_Intersecs(geom1, ST_Buffer(geom2,1000)) except that the first is much more efficient.

Comment: You are completely right! I ended up using you suggested ST_DWithin. It worked much faster compared to use the combined query. 40 seconds faster!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your first query in the from clause of the 2nd: something like that should work:

`SELECT 
    building.id
    building.address
FROM 
    building, 
    (SELECT
        event_point.id,
        event_point.geom,
        st_buffer(event_point.geom, 100) AS buffergeom
    FROM public.event_point) buffer
WHERE
    ST_within(building.geom, buffer.buffergeom)`

Comment: This only works if there is only one row in the event_point table; otherwise you'll need a WHERE clause to limit to one row, or a JOIN to merge multiple rows correctly.

Comment: This worked, thanks for explaining it how to build a query like that! However, I ended up using John Barca suggestion because the query was much faster to return